# Problems using CacheManager.downloadAreaAsync from OSMBonuspack

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am just writing an app which should be able to prefetch Maptiles to use the app in places where no data connection is available. For this reason I use Open Street Maps and on my Android client OSMDroid and OSMdroid Bonuspack. For production I will use my own OSM server.

This is my code for downloading the tiles of a defined area:

```
map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

BoundingBoxE6 boxE6 = new BoundingBoxE6(51.758971, 7.100778, 50.653902, 6.689312);
CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager(map);
cacheManager.downloadAreaAsync(getActivity(), boxE6, 13, 15);
```

My build.gradle contains all dependencies which are needed, according to the GitHub page of OSMdroid Bonuspack (of course no build errors):

```
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.0.1@aar'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile project(':osmbonuspack_v5.4')
```

When I run my code, the dialog appears and shows the progress of downloading the tiles for each zoom level. But my logcat flooded with the following error:

```
Error downloading MapTile: /15/17015/11010
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.osmdroid.http.HttpClientFactory
at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.cachemanager.CacheManager.loadTile(CacheManager.java:95)
at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.cachemanager.CacheManager$DownloadingTask.downloadArea(CacheManager.java:259)
at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.cachemanager.CacheManager$DownloadingTask.doInBackground(CacheManager.java:230)
at org.osmdroid.bonuspack.cachemanager.CacheManager$DownloadingTask.doInBackground(CacheManager.java:207)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Proguard is disabled.

Comment: Which versions of osmdroid and OSMBonusPack are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As I was not able to find out, why org.osmdroid.http.HttpClientFactory is missing, I have created `FixedCacheManager` and overrode `loadTile()`. Inside this method I use OkHttp to download the tiles:

```
@Override
    public boolean loadTile(OnlineTileSourceBase tileSource, MapTile tile) {
        File file = this.getFileName(tileSource, tile);
        if(file.exists()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            InputStream in = null;
            BufferedOutputStream out = null;

            boolean var15;
            try {
                String e = tileSource.getTileURLString(tile);
                Request request = new Request.Builder().get().url(e).build();
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                if(!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.w("BONUSPACK", "Problem downloading MapTile: " + tile + " HTTP response: " + response.code());
                    boolean entity1 = false;
                    return entity1;
                }

                final ResponseBody body = response.body();
                if(body == null) {
                    Log.w("BONUSPACK", "No content downloading MapTile: " + tile);
                    boolean dataStream1 = false;
                    return dataStream1;
                }

                in = body.byteStream();
                ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, 8192);
                StreamUtils.copy(in, out);
                out.flush();
                byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
                ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                this.mTileWriter.saveFile(tileSource, tile, byteStream);
                byteStream.reset();
                var15 = true;
            } catch (UnknownHostException var22) {
                Log.w("BONUSPACK", "UnknownHostException downloading MapTile: " + tile + " : " + var22);
                return false;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException var23) {
                Log.w("BONUSPACK", "Tile not found: " + tile + " : " + var23);
                return false;
            } catch (IOException var24) {
                Log.w("BONUSPACK", "IOException downloading MapTile: " + tile + " : " + var24);
                return false;
            } catch (Throwable var25) {
                Log.e("BONUSPACK", "Error downloading MapTile: " + tile, var25);
                return false;
            } finally {
                StreamUtils.closeStream(in);
                StreamUtils.closeStream(out);
            }

            return var15;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It was removed because google doesn't want us using Apache Http Client anymore, this it was no long relevant. OSM Bonus back was also updated to reflect the change. Maybe something was missed.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: you have mismatched osmdroid and osmbonus packs.

You need osmdroid 5.0.1 with osmbonuspack 5.5.

Reason: osmdroid 5.x supports the newer android apis (or lack thereof). osmbonuspack was also updated to support those changes.... in v5.5